# AND-OR Graph from Horn clauses

Tags: graphs, automation, logic

Does anyone know if there is a way to generate a nice graph from Horn clauses? for example:

[image: AND-OR graph]

Ideally, I would like to generate AND-OR graphs like this directly from Horn clauses written in Latex; however, if you know another way such as from rules written in RDF, I will also appreciate it.

Also, generated graphs do not have to be exactly like this one I show. It just have to illustrate the inference relation between my data.

Comment: Have you looked at part 4 of the TikZ manual, 'Graph Drawing'? It uses Lua to automate graph drawing. You'd need to specify things in the right syntax or transform the clauses into that syntax, but it does automate the drawing of graphs. (Requires LuaTeX, of course.)

Comment: @cfr I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a potential solution using `neato` from the `graphviz` package.  It requires a more difficult input format and the output isn't as nice as your example, but I think it conveys the right information.

A file named `sample.dot` as follows...

```
graph G
{
    P -- Q [dir=forward];

    L -- LM;
    M -- LM;
    LM -- P [dir=forward];

    B -- BL;
    L -- BL;
    BL -- M [dir=forward];

    A -- AP;
    P -- AP;
    AP -- L [dir=forward];

    A -- AB;
    B -- AB;
    AB -- L [dir=forward];

    LM [shape=point];
    BL [shape=point];
    AP [shape=point];
    AB [shape=point];
}
```

processed with the following command...

```
neato -Tpdf sample.dot -o sample.pdf
```

gives...

[image]